# Clear all subdirectories, but not remove them in NAnt

Tags: continuous-integration, nant

How to clear subdirectories without removing them in NAnt?

As the result of script execution, I need a directory with the same subdirectories, but empty:

```
<delete>
  <fileset basedir="\\${conf.server.frontend}\wwwroot">
    <include name="???" />
  </fileset>
</delete>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
<delete>
    <fileset basedir="\\${conf.server.frontend}\wwwroot">
        <include name="**\*" />
    </fileset>
</delete>
```